# Software for hosting, managing and streaming video

Tags: video, frameworks, video-streaming, platform

I need some kind of the software for video-hosting (open-source or commercial)
It should be able to record video from cams, allows instant access to video-records by the time, support streaming, be highly adjustable.

What options are there and how I can find them? I would appreciate some ideas or concrete suggestions or just relevant key words I can use to find some information about this kind of the software.

I am not looking for already established video-hosting service, accessible from the Web. I want to build my own, which will be used in the intranet.

Answer (score 2):

There are various such software. For .net Windows platform if you wish to host or stream your videos over IIS then Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 Pro is such a software. You can easily manage all the hosting related things. You can broadcast live videos , or videos via files to IIS. Though to enable IIS to stream videos , you have to install IIS media services first !! You can install media services by [clicking here.](http://www.iis.net/media)

[image]

After installing media services , you will see the Media Services section in IIS mamanger. After doing all this , you can install Expression Encoder 4 and start working.

[Click here](http://www.iis.net/learn/media/on-demand-smooth-streaming/getting-started-with-iis-smooth-streaming#setup) to know how to set up smooth streaming using IIS media services and Expression Encoder 4.

Comment: I have a very similar requirement to Peter17 and I was hoping to use IIS and its Media Services but Expression Encoder 4 is no longer available or supported.  Do you know of a free or reasonably priced (less than £1000) alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late, but I'm currently investigating a solution for similar requirements.

The second half of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_hosting_services provides good starting point under the 'White-label providers', 'Enterprise video hosting providers' and 'Open source video sharing' headings.

[Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/) seems to promising, as they have a hosted service and also provide their platform as Open Source software.

Answer (score 0):

Flash media encoder software lets you to have the either a [live video streaming](http://hioxindia.com/live-stream-hosting.php) or the videos that were recorded. But FFMpeg would support you with the recorded videos and you do have the softwares like PHP motions, ClipShare.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a list of various open source software , hopefully you can find one u need.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open_source_software_packages

Also search for digital asset management.